A pedagogical explanation for matrix evolution and Schrödinger equation
What is the mathematical connection between Hermitian evolution from state $|\psi\rangle$ to $\langle\chi|$,
$$\langle\chi|H|\psi\rangle$$
as matrix expression, and the time evolution expressed with the Schrödinger equation as continuous functions?
"Pedagogical" here means to have mathematical steps on objects explained.
Edit: Based on responses, to make question a bit more specific, How do we express quantum dynamical evolution from one quantum-state to another?

Could you clarify what do you mean with "matrix evolution?"

Are you assuming that $|\chi\rangle$ and $|\psi\rangle$ are members of an orthonormal basis? Because that's the simplest context in which to understand this. Also, what do you mean by a "pedagogical explanation"? Depending on how far you want this "pedagogical explanation" to go, this question could be too broad (i.e., recapitulating Dirac notation, linear algebra, solutions to coupled, homogeneous, linear, constant-coefficient ordinary differential equations, and the postulates of quantum mechanics, etc.) Perhaps you can edit your question to be more specific as to what you want here.

@Ruffolo Matrix representation in describing quantum dynamics.

@march yes, evolution of one quantum state to another is expressed. Edited. Pedagogical meant to be steps of derivation are explained.

I honestly do not understand the question. Could you clarify by stating an example and or rephrasing?

@TobiasFünke Sure. Essentially,  how do we express  quantum-state dynamics? Just to give you a context, question arise due to Ed Witten's recent tutorial, he said, quantum evolution is governed by $H$ and transition is expressed by  $\langle\chi|H|\psi\rangle$. Eric below had some good pointers in this direction, projective vs. unitary evolution.

The dynamical evolution can be described in terms of a unitary time evolution operator. The Schrödinger equation is
$$ i\hbar \frac{d|\psi(t)\rangle}{dt}=\hat{H}|\psi(t)\rangle.$$
We can write its formal solution as (assuming the Hamiltonian is time-independent)
$$|\psi(t)\rangle= \exp{\left(-\frac{i(t-t_0)\hat{H}}{\hbar}\right)}|\psi(t_0)\rangle=\hat{U}(t)|\psi(t_0)\rangle.$$
$\hat{U}$ is unitary, since the Hamiltonian is self-adjoint.
Given a wave function $\psi(q,t_0)$ at some initial time $t_0$, how can we express the wave function at some later time $t>t_0$? First of all, we have to recall that a wave function is actually a coefficient of the expansion of the quantum state $|\psi\rangle$ in terms of eigenstates $|q\rangle$ of the position operator. You may be familiar with expanding the state in terms of eigenstates of some self adjoint operator, which form a orthonormal basis of the given Hilbert space. So we write something like $|\psi\rangle= \sum_n c_n |n\rangle$. The $m$-th coefficient $c_m$ is $\langle m|\psi\rangle$. Here, we are using the eigenstate of the position operator and thus we can write $\psi(q,t)=\langle q|\psi(t)\rangle$. To move further, we use the fact that the sum of all states forming a orthonormal basis is the identity. To prove this, just act on this operator on any state:
$$ \sum_n |n\rangle \langle n|\psi\rangle = \sum_n |n\rangle \langle n |\sum_m c_m|m\rangle = \sum_{m,n} c_m|n\rangle \langle n| m\rangle=\sum_{m,n} c_m|n\rangle \delta_{mn}=\sum_n c_n |n\rangle=|\psi\rangle$$
The eigestates of the position operator are continuous rather than discrete, so the sum is replaced by an integral:
$$\int dq \, |q\rangle \langle q|= 1$$
We can then apply the trick of inserting a one in terms of that integral:
$$\psi(q,t)=\langle q|\psi(t)\rangle=\langle q|\hat{U}(t,t_0)|\psi(t_0)\rangle=\langle q|\hat{U}(t,t_0)\left(\int dq_0 |q_0\rangle\langle q_0|\right)|\psi(t_0)\rangle = \int dq_0 \,K(q,q_0; t,t_0)\psi(q_0,t_0)$$
and one defines the propagator as
$$K(q,q_0;t,t_0)=\langle q|\hat{U}(t,t_0)|q_0\rangle.$$
The propagator gives the quantum mechanical amplitude for the transition between an initial state $|q_0\rangle$ at time $t_0$ and a final state $|q\rangle$ at time $t$.
An extra comment. In quantum computing, it is possible to achieve unitary evolution using measurements. The corresponding formalism is known as measurement based quantum computation where gates (unitary operators) can be simulated by performing local measurements on a specific cluster of states.

(+1 and accepted) Good answer. Could you update in the answer if possible: (1) What does this expression means $\psi(q,t)=\langle q|\psi(t)\rangle$ ? (2) What's the meaning of the  integral appears there?  Some references to literature also appreciated.

I updated the answer. This is basic notion in quantum mechanics, I assume you can read of it in any textbook on quantum mechanics.

Cool! OP aimed at basic notions for more "pedagogical understanding".


Hermitian evolution from state $|\psi\rangle$ to $\langle\chi|$,

That's wrong. The state of the system is denoted by ket notation $|\ldots\rangle$, which, let's say belongs to the Hilbert Space $\mathcal{H}$. Then bra notation $\langle\ldots|$ lives in the dual space $\mathcal{H}^*$.
$$\langle A|\equiv |A\rangle ^{\dagger}$$
Most of the time, a system follows unitary evolution dictated by Schrödinger equation. When a measurement is made, the system follows projective evolution, which is intrinsically probabilistic. The system will have probability $\langle \chi_i |H| \psi \rangle$ to collapse into the eigenstate $|\chi_i\rangle$. Then in the future, the system will evolve starting from the state $|\chi_i\rangle$ to which it collapsed.
The measurement problem is unsolved (That's the conclusion. Many introductory textbooks don't say this clearly, causing a lot of confusions). The theory doesn't define what a measurement is (when projective evolution should be invoked). However, projective evolution is a necessary ad hoc in the axioms of quantum mechanics, because Schrödinger equation always gives unitary time evolution, while projective evolution is non-unitary.
Working out this example will be very helpful for your understanding.

What is the mathematical connection between Hermitian evolution from state $|\psi\rangle$ to $\langle\chi|$, $\langle\chi|H|\psi\rangle$ as matrix expression and the time evolution expressed with the Schrödinger equation as continuous functions? A pedagogical explanation.

Therefore, they have no connection. One is projective evolution. The latter is unitary evolution.

Some extra comments regarding the confusions you might have.
Quantum states (a.k.a. wavefunctions) live in a Hilbert space. That is an infinite dimensional vector space. Every vector space has a basis if you acknowledge Axiom of Choice. Once a basis is specified, you can write any linear operator as a matrix (so don't be confused about operators in matrix form and continuous wavefunctions!).

It is not quite true that unitary evolution and projective measurements have no connection. In quantum computing, they are indeed equivalent. Any gate (unitary operators) can be achieved via a suitable measurement pattern on a particular cluster of qubits. The formalism is known as measurement based quantum computation.

Gave +1, expression being transition probability  is insightful.
